# Why is rust async forcing the implementors to use dynamic dispatch for `Waker`

Tags: rust, async-await, traits, dynamic-dispatch

I was reading about how async/await was [implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/task/index.html) in rust and I noticed that the `RawWaker` is essentially a fat pointer. I don't quite understand why the `Waker` is implemented essentially like `struct Waker{data: *const (), vtable: *const WakerVTable}` rather than `Waker<T: Wakes>{raw_walker: &mut T}` which would allow the compiler to know the implementations of `wake()`, `wake_ref()`, `drop()` and `clone()` at compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wakers need to be incredibly versatile. [This blog](https://boats.gitlab.io/blog/post/wakers-i/) explains a lot about the design choices, and it's worth a read. The relevant part says this:

> The only requirement that the poll phase introduces is dynamism: because it needs to be passed through arbitrary futures, the waker type cannot be generic. This means that every requirement introduced by the other two phases needs to be **dynamically dispatched**.

Now the part that the author wasn't clear on here is that "arbitrary futures" includes [boxed futures](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/type.BoxFuture.html) (and futures which can be polled using dynamic dispatch in general). If the definition of the future trait were the following:

```rs
pub trait Future {
    type Output;

    fn poll<W: Wake>(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_, W>,
    ) -> Poll<Self::Output>;
}
```

then the trait `Future` would not be [object safe](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0255-object-safety.html), eliminating the possibility of dynamic dispatch, which was a deal-breaker.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for that, could you expand a bit in the BoxFuture and what object safe means?

Comment: A `BoxFuture` is a future on the heap which you can poll through dynamic dispatch. The type definition I linked is very long but the important part is `dyn Future`. In order for something to be turned into a trait object (read indirection + `dyn Trait`), the trait must be object safe which encompasses a [number of requirements](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0255-object-safety.html). The reason that having a type parameter on a method makes it non-object safe is that the vtable would essentially have to contain a pointer to each monomorphized form of the method, which is infeasible.